# chart.js time x-axis - start ticks at specific time

Tags: chart.js

In chart.js 3 I have a 'time' x-axis.  I'm using a callback in ticks to show hours since a specific time like so:

```
           ticks: {
              display: true,
              callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
                var tickMS = ticks[index].value;
                var diffMS = tickMS - _this.startMS;
                var diffHour = diffMS / 1000 / 60 / 60;
                return diffHour;
              }
            }
```

This works fine, however the ticks displayed are fractions of an hour like this:

[image]

How can I set the ticks to start at _this.startMS so that the ticks displayed are on the hour (since _this.startMS) showing 8, 16 etc. rather than 7.8889...?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a min property like so:

```js
scales: {
  x: {
    min: _this.startMS
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lee, I tried it but it doesn't seem to make any different.  type: 'time' if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - for my purposes, setting min: didn't work, so instead I've disabled the scale and used the annotations plugin to draw my own